# How to split html string to DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html string

```
var str = '<span class="linq" onclick="ShowData(2,-1,1);">11111</span> &nbsp;»&nbsp; <span class="linq" onclick="ShowData(16,1,1);">22222</span> &nbsp;»&nbsp; 33333';
```

I need to split it to an array.

```
arr[0] = "<span class="linq" onclick="ShowData(2,-1,1);">11111</span>";
arr[1] = "&nbsp;»&nbsp;"
arr[2] = "<span class="linq" onclick="ShowData(16,1,1);">22222</span>";
arr[3] = "&nbsp;»&nbsp; 33333'"
```

I tried to use $.parseHTML() but i'm using jquery 1.6 and can't upgrade for now.
If i use $(str) i get an array but without the last item.

```
arr[0] = "<span class="linq" onclick="ShowData(2,-1,1);">11111</span>";
arr[1] = "&nbsp;»&nbsp;"
arr[2] = "<span class="linq" onclick="ShowData(16,1,1);">22222</span>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = str;

var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(temp.childNodes, function(node) {
    return node.nodeType === 1 
         ? node.outerHTML
         : node.nodeValue;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's dirty, but you can do something like

```
str = str + '<span></span>';
```

Now $str should return all the object you need plus an useless object, remember not to use the last object returned and you are ok

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = str.match(/<.+?[a-z]>|[^<]+/g);
```

Subject it to some testing first though.