# How to change the split location in the text if the text contain html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code dynamically shortened text with “Read More” link using Jquery. I don't want this function to split a string that is covered with html tags. In case there are HTML tags I want the function to cut the string after the closing tag even if it exceed the limit of 100 chars. Any idea how can I do it ?

```
function ResponsiveDesc() {
    var limit = 100;
    var isHTML = RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/(<([^>]+)>)/i);
    var chars = $("#ResponsiveDescription").html();
    //alert(isHTML($("#ResponsiveDescription").html()));
    if (chars.length > limit) {
        var visiblePart = $("<span> " + chars.substr(0, limit - 1) + "</span>");
        var dots = $("<span class='dots'>... </span>");
        var hiddenPart = $("<span class='more'>" + chars.substr(limit - 1) + "</span>");
        var readMore = $("<span class='read-more'>Read More</span>");

        readMore.click(function () {
            $(this).prev().remove(); // remove dots
            $(this).next().show(); //show hiddenPart
            $(this).remove(); // remove readMore
        });

        $("#ResponsiveDescription").empty()
            .append(visiblePart)
            .append(dots)
            .append(readMore)
            .append(hiddenPart);
    }
```

Comment: So if the html contains "<span>1000s chars of text<span>" then it basically ignores your 100char limit?

Comment: If the html contain "Hello world, thank you for this <b>beautiful day</b> this sunday". I don't want the function to split the following string "<b>beautiful day</b> ", I want function to split after the "</b>".

Comment: I'm assuming this is because you are *manually* applying the ellipses and if you break half-way through the <b> you'll be left with the rest of the page in bold?   You can fix this with a tiny amount of css if you're interested in a non-js solution.

Comment: I need a js solution.

Comment: Shame, cause one line of css will save you a whole word of pain trying to parse html, and, like I say, any tags will completely ruin your 100char limit anyway.   Is this a class assignment by some chance?  If so, you should provide an (additional, still complete the assignment) alternative solution using css because a js solution would not be a real-world solution.    It's here if you're interested in how easy it is:  https://jsfiddle.net/mo6wydve/

Comment: For js, split the text into parts then add them one at time until total length > 100.  You can use this as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355637/how-to-split-html-string-to-dom-elements

Comment: And if the string in covered by anchor tags like  ""Hello world, thank you for this <a href="">beautiful day</a> this Sunday" ? I want to cover all the situations.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mo6wydve/1/